# Эпиграф... или чем обозначить начало, по аналогии эпилога и пролога?

Tags: выбор-слов, семантика

Речь идёт о поиске чего-либо для обозначения начала текста, под стать "эпилогу", "вступление" не подходит.

Comment: Обязательно было политоту сюда притащить? Или это и было целью? Учитывая бессмысленность самого вопроса, очень на то похоже. Достали вы, интернетные воины, загадили уже всё что только можно.

Comment: Обозначают знаками, начинают словами. Если нужно и то, и другое — так это буквица. Вы определитесь и перефразируйте вопрос в этой части

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, я не поняла, о чём идёт речь.

```
        Чем обозначить начало?
```

Текст обычно начинается  экспозицией.

Значение слова Экспозиция по Ефремовой:

> Экспозиция - 1. Часть литературного произведения, в которой
>   характеризуется обстановка, излагаются обстоятельства, предшествующие
>   началу действия.
>
> 2. Первый раздел музыкального произведения - сонаты или фуги, содержащий изложение основной темы или основных тем данного
>      произведения.
> 3. Размещение в определенной системе предметов, выставляемых для обозрения. // Собрание таких выставляемых предметов. // Место, где
>      такое собрание расположено.

А эпиграф - цитата перед текстом, которая передаёт основной смысл последующего текста.